# spring boot microservices got Connection refused with chaining request

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I have an issue with chaining requests in a microservices architecture with Spring Boot.

Assume the following:

- App A makes a request to App B to update some inventory data
- App B processes the request from App A and requires some data from App A to complete the processing
- App B makes a request to App A in order to process the request from App A
- App A does not process the second request coming from App B until the first request is finished

--!! Both App A and App B always do authentication and store the user inside `SecurityContextHolder` before processing any request (I'm not sure if this is because the same user exists in the security context holder) and also I'm using restTemplate to make all the internal request.

Below is the error message I am receiving:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://appA/id": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: "Connection refused" should happen way before any logic inside SecurityContextHolder. You should post the code of the client performing the request or, even better, a minimal example.

Comment: I can make the request if it doesn't chain request back to app A. The app A refuse the connection until it finish the first request for the same user.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Did you manage to reproduce the issue? Is app A refusing all the connections while handling the first request?

Comment: I'm using embedded server tomcat. Yes i can reproduce it in local. For now i pass the data required along with first request from app A to B which is for me violated the micro service architecture. Its not directly refuse, but it wait until timeout.

Comment: Post the code and the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

the answer below might be a bit confusing to compare with the question above. but this is what i did to solve the above issue in production that having high load request.

[1] Initially i have the issue which the new thread spawn not having all the necessary attribute to do authentication in other micro app and my solution i implement was extending the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and copy the RequestContextHolder into the new thread.  ref https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/729  (this is for graphql but fundamental for thread spawn is still same)

[2] after that the issue was when i started using @Async to improve the apps performance. when every loop will spawn a new thread which taking a slow operation to finish and by the time the main thread is already finish the operation and cause the request attribute to be clean by garbage collector.
ref https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/integrations/concurrency.html#_delegatingsecuritycontextexecutor

below is the first solution [1] i implemented to solve the request attribute :

```
@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("x-executor-");
    return taskExecutor; <---- i should use a delegating thread class
}
```

and below is the solution second solution [2] to solve the next issue:

```
@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("x-executor-");
    taskExecutor.initialize(); <-- this line
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);  <-- this line
}
```